# Получение данных из запроса | mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysqlconnector

переходил с sqlite3 на mysql.connector и всё ощущается по другому. И не могу разобраться к примеру вот есть запрос:

```
def get_info(userid):
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `discord_accounts` WHERE `DiscordID` = %s", (userid, ))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row is not None:
        return row
    return None

data = get_info(userid)
```

Как мне использовать данные полученные в data?
в sqlite3 это работает так: `data['DiscordID']`
А в mysql так и не могу понять

Comment: А в чём у вас проблема-то? Посмотрите, что лежит внутри `data`, почитайте документацию по соответствующему типу данных и пользуйтесь на здоровье

Comment: @andreymal выводит примерно это ('.EOS', 1238491854, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) а как извлечь к примеру 1238491854 я не знаю

Comment: Самый обычный кортеж с обычным доступом по обычным индексам `data[1]`

Comment: а ну ладно я про это не знал, я не вглубляюсь в изучения Python а всего лишь разбираюсь в языке C